# How to get the text between any number of parenthesis?

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

Suppose I have a document where I want to capture the strings that have parenthesis before or after.

Example: `This [is] a {{test}} sentence. The (((end))).`

So basically I want to get the words `is`, `test` and `end`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also you can use `[\[\{\(]+(\w+)[\]\}\)]+`

Comment: You need something like this: `(?:\[+|\(+|\{+)([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\]+|\)+|\}+)`
See example: https://regex101.com/r/2fPHIK/1/

Comment: Clarification needed: 1. does the closing parenthesis have to match the opening one? 2. "capture strings that have parenthesis before OR after." Does this mean that "end)" should result in match "end"?

Comment: What is the expected result for: `(This is) {[a)} [[t)e{s}t].]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your condition "*strings that have parenthesis before **or** after*" - any word could be proceeded with OR only followed by some type of parentheses:

```
$text = 'This [is] a {{test}} sentence. The (((end))). Some word))';
preg_match_all('/(?:\[+|\{+|\(+)(\w+)|(\w+)(?:\]+|\}+|\)+)/', $text, $m);
$result = array_filter(array_merge($m[1],$m[2]));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => is
    [1] => test
    [2] => end
    [7] => word
)
```

Comment: Question is: should closing symbol match the opening one? what to do about '{{test)}'? is the match 'test' or 'test)'? Your regex gives 'test' as result, which is - don't get me wrong - not wrong per se. OP not clear.

Comment: @mlambrichs. read again the description from question *strings that have parenthesis before **OR** after*

Answer (score 1):

Your regex could be:

```
[\[{(]((?(?<=\[)[^\[\]]+|(?(?<={)[^{}]+|[^()]+)))
```

Explanation: the if-then-else construction is needed to make sure that an opening '{' is matched against a closing '}', etc.

```
[\[{(]                                   # Read [, { or (
((?(?<=\[)                               # Lookbehind: IF preceding char is [
 [^\[\]]+                                # THEN read all chars unequal to [ and ]
 |                                       # ELSE
 (?(?<={)                                # IF preceding char is {
 [^{}]+                                  # THEN read all chars unequal to { and }
 |                                       # ELSE
 [^()]+)))                               # read all chars unequal to ( and )
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OH26UT/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
(?<=\(|\[|{)[^()\[\]{}]+
```

[>>>Demo<<<](https://regex101.com/r/U2It51/1)

OR this one:

```
(?<=\(|{|\[)(?!\(|{|\[)[^)\]}]+
```

[>>>Demo<<<](https://regex101.com/r/U2It51/2)

**Explantion(for the 1st regex):**

- `(?<=\(|\[|{)` - Positive lookbehind - looks for a zero-length match just preceeded by a `{` or `[` or a `(`
- `[^()\[\]{}]+` - one or more occurences of any character which is not amoong the following characters: `[`, `(`, `{`, `}`, `)`, `]`

**Explanation(for 2nd Regex):**

- `(?<=\(|\[|{)` - Positive lookbehind - looks for a zero-length match just preceeded by a `{` or `[` or a `(`
- `(?!\(|{|\[)` - Negative lookahead - In the previous step, it found the position which is just preceded by an opening bracket. This piece of regex verifies that it is not followed by another opening bracket. Hence, matching the position just after the innermost opening bracket - `(`, `{` or `[`.
- `[^)\]}]+` - One or more occurrences of characters which are not among these closing brackets - `]`, `}`, `)`

Comment: Same here: the question is: should closing symbol match the opening one? what to do about '{{test)}'? is the match 'test' or 'test)'? Your regex gives 'test' as result, which is - don't get me wrong - not wrong per se. OP not clear.

Comment: @mlambrichs Check my 2nd regex. It covers that scenario too.

Comment: No it doesn't. It clearly matches 'ofs ' in '([[({{ofs )}}}}}))))'. The question is if that's correct, or if the match should be 'ofs )'.

Comment: Yup. Need a clarification for that then. The question is unclear/incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me.

```
<?php

$in = "This [is] a {{test}} sentence. The (((end))).";
preg_match_all('/(?<=\(|\[|{)[^()\[\]{}]+/', $in, $out);
echo $out[0][0]."<br>".$out[0][1]."<br>".$out[0][2];
?>
```